# SSIS Inserting text into int column

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012

I have an SSIS package that reads from one table and inserts into another.  The source table is a varchar(50) and the destination is int.  I am not doing any explicit conversions.

On the destination step, I am looking at the advanced column properties and I see the Input Column as type DT_STR length 50.  The External column is type DT_I4 length 4.

When I try to copy a value such as 99.00, I get 0 in the destination.

I have been unable to reproduce this on my local workstation, but I can see it happening in production... Locally, I get 99.  What else should I be looking at?

Comment: Note - both tables are in the same database on the same server.  SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Is fixing the package to explicitly convert from DT_STR 50 to int an option?

Comment: Yeah - I can trim the trailing zeros and explicitly convert to int - that would be the right way.  My question was more about how to reproduce this.  When I try locally, 99.00 gets inserted as 99.  I don't have full access to production where this is happening.  I can see the source, destination, and extract the code from the server.    If I can't definitively recreate the problem, how do I assure others that I have solved it?  If I cannot reproduce, I don't have root cause.

Comment: Oh, is this the project deployment model? Do the packages run out of the SSISDB? If so, perhaps you can use a Data Tap to capture the data in-between the penultimate component and the destination. That would show the values that are being sent to the destination.

Answer (score 0):

> The source table is a varchar(50) and the destination is int. I am not
>   doing any explicit conversions.

Playing with fire you are, as this will introduce errors if the value is not convertable to an integer.  A superior idea would be to use a derived column task to convert to an integer for those values that can convert, and then test for any values that could not be converted and handle them gracefully.